# Validating fields when submitting form Jquery

Tags: jquery, validation

I am really new to Jquery, but want to learn it. I came quite far with the tutorial all over the web, but now I want to validate a form before submitting it, and I can't find a simple example for this.

I have a form:

```
<form id="testform">
<input name="test" type="input">
<input type="submit" value="TEST">
</form>
```

I have this function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#testform').submit(function(){


            $.get('test.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data){
                $('#test').html(data);
            });             
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Now what I want is quite simple, make the background color of the name field RED of it is empty. Please explain how to do this!

---

Looked at your answer, and it does not seem to work. When hitting the submit button, nothing happens, only the form clears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
$('#testform').submit(function(e) {
      if ($('input[name=test]').val() == "") { // if the input is empty
           $('input[name=test]').css('background-color','red')
           return false
      } else {
         $.get('test.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data){
              $('#test').html(data);
         });             
      }
      return false
});
```

Comment: That's not what he meant I suppose (still trying to figure it out though :P )

Comment: @fliespl maybe I have figured it out `:)`

Comment: `input[name=type]` should be `input[name=test]`

Comment: np :)  Also might want to add a `return false;` or `event.preventDefault()` or some such in there

Comment: Fixed it! Had to paste the script you provided AFTER the form, I had it before the form.
Please explain why this is?

Comment: you should wrap the code wihin `$(document).ready(function() {` to make sure that the script is executed after All DOM nodes are ready to be manipulated.

Comment: It fixed it because DOM elements must exist when the code executes.  Wrapping the code inside a `document.ready` function would also fix it because it waits for DOM to load before executing.

Answer (score 0):

As a fellow jquery newbie, I would say a couple of things here:

First, if you're just going to validate a couple of little things, you should absolutely write your own code. It'll be much lighter than using a plugin (probably...)

However, if you're validating quite a lot, you might want to look into jquery validation plugins (like http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) as these can make life a lot easier.

(Also, I'm sure you know this already, but don't forget the server-side validation, as client-side can fail!)

Happy coding!

Comment: This is not an answer.  Should be a comment instead.